# Ignore an event that is used by another event

Tags: javascript, jquery, single-page-application

I am working with a single-page website and I am having trouble with the highlighting of the navigation item upon reaching its corresponding content. Now, I will be simplifying my code.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="home">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div id="about">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div id="blog">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div id="contact">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // function that scrolls automatically to the content of a certain menu item. Just 
    // like scroll-to.js

    // .scroll event that automatically sets the "current" class to the list item when
    // when it reached its corresponding div.
});
```

This works perfectly when I just scroll up and down the page. The problem is when I click the list items. For example, the currently highlighted item is "Home" then I want to go to "Contact" by clicking it. Since the highlighting is manipulated in a .scroll event, the two buttons in between "Home" and "Contact" will be highlighted too because my click will pass through them from "Home" to "Contact".

Is there any way that I can ignore the items in between? Thanks.

Comment: I sort of get what you mean, but you'll need to post a lot more code to get help. In particular please post the code you use to highlight by clicking, and it would probably also be good to post the code in your scroll event (unless they are one and the same). The scroll event shouldn't be affecting the click event.

Answer (score 0):

Use a handler with a different namespace when you trigger a scroll event from a click event

```
$('li').on('click', function(){
  $(window).trigger('scroll.autoscroll');
});

$(window).on('scroll.autoscroll', function(){
  //whatever you want to happen on a scroll event triggered by a click event
});
```

Or you can use the .trigger method to pass data to your event handler like:
`$(window).trigger('scroll', pass_some_data);`
then let your event handler decide what to do based on the data it was passed.

Hope that helps. I can't be any more specific since you basically just posted an empty function with comment lines in it.